# 3 weeks later vs after 3 weeks

Tags: time

I'm little bit confused of using **later** and **after** to mention a specific time in the future. For example, I wanted to say:

I'll be on a vacation for 3 days after precisely 21 days.

Can I also say that:

- I'll be on a vacation for 3 days 3 weeks later.
- I'll be on a vacation for 3 days after 3 weeks.
- I'll be on a vacation for 3 days in 3 weeks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **later** *adverb*
> :  at some time subsequent to a given time
> [- M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/later)
>
> **after** *adverb*
> :  following in time or place
> [- M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/after)
>
> **in** *preposition*
> 3b : at the end of (a period of time)
> *I'll be there in a minute.*
> [- M-W](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/definition/in)

Use the third option, "in 3 weeks". The other two options sound better with an explicit starting time-reference.